# Incorrect pagination in jsGrid

Tags: javascript, jsgrid

I am using `jsGrid` plugin in my project.
I have an issue : Total records in my `DB = 170,
set pageSize: 150,`
On loadData received 118 (itemsCount:118) records but still get pagination at bottom of the table.
As per logic pagination button should not be display because received record < pageSize so no pagination should be display and when click on page 2 "Not Found " message display.

Below is my jsgrid configuration:

```
height: "880px",
width: "100%",
filtering: false,
editing: true,
inserting: false,
sorting: true,
paging: true,
pageLoading: true,
autoload: true,
pageSize: 150,
pageIndex: 1,
pageButtonCount: 5,
deleteConfirm: "Do you really want to delete this task?",
controller: db,
```

Please help

Comment: @Olayinka O Do you have the full code example of loading the data into the grid?

Comment: @nickgowdy no, I only edited the original question.

Comment: How are you assigning the data? With the controller property? I'm using this codepen and the pagination works properly: https://codepen.io/whitneyland/pen/aWVJbE

Comment: Ahhh.. have fixed this issue, actually itemsCount = no of records you want to fetched from table not total record in table